# MATLAB's makecform in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I use MATLAB's makecform in a script. However, the script takes a while to run, so I want to run it on a server. On this server, I have Octave instead of MATLAB.

Octave cannot find the function makecform.

I Googled the problem and found that this is not implemented in Octave, but that was from a mailing list in 2013. Is there (now) an alternative function for makecform in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say about the alternatives but I can confirm that the function is not yet implemented.

the `makecform` function belongs to the image package from Octave Forge.

`makecform` is present in the missing functions list of the package. You can see the evidence for the same in this [link](http://wiki.octave.org/Image_package#Missing_functions).

If you have some idea about how to implement the function, feel free to contribute.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement it. I will look for another solution.